# Animate one fragment being slid in on top of the other?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I want to switch between two fragments so that the new fragment gets slid in from the bottom on top of the old fragment. The sliding is pretty straight forward, using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:fromYDelta="100%"
               android:toYDelta="0"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
               android:duration="200"/>
</set>
```

and `FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations()`.

The problem is that my fragments don't have a solid background (I'm doing this in a `DrawerLayout` with a semi transparent background). So when the new fragment is slid on top of the old, the old one is still visible until the animation is finished, whereupon it suddenly disappears from the background.

To solve this, I'd like for the old fragment to be "clipped", i.e. it's height should be animated but it shouldn't be scaled or moved. This should produce the correct effect, but I'm not sure if it can be done, and if so, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I am facing a same problem it is my solution to resolve the problem please try this code i think it helps you:

**For example**

xml.layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<translate android:duration="150" android:fromXDelta="100%p" 
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
 android:toXDelta="0" />
 </set>
```

java class

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

MyFragment next = getMyFragment();

ft.add(R.id.MyLayout,next);
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right,0);
ft.show(next);
ft.commit();
```

It work fines but the older Fragment is still visible, use this line it is not visible during the animation.

```
ft.remove(myolderFrag);
```